# Google Maps Geocoding API throws error when using place_id as a search parameter

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get the longtitude and the latitude for a specific place_id in Google Maps Geocoding API, but I am getting an error. Based on the [python api documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/geocoding.py) there is a parameter place_id that can be used.

When I am running the code below, I am getting the following error:
**geocode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'place_id'**

```
import googlemaps
from secret_key import key

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=key)
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(place_id = 'ChIJgUbEo8cfqokR5lP9_Wh_DaM')
geocode_result
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on googlemaps 4.10.0 with Python 3.11.4

Comment: What version of googlemaps do you have installed? try running: >>>import googlemaps >>>print(googlemaps.__version__) or just check with pip freeze

Comment: I had installed googlemaps from conda. I installed the library from pip, restarted the notebook and it worked. Currently I am using 4.10.0 version. Thanks a lot for the response.